# about the use of metadata in elastic search

Tags: java, api, elasticsearch, metadata

I would like to ask how the **metadata** data structure in **elastic search** is used when executing various **apis**. Will **a copy of the metadata be saved**  at the beginning of each call to the api? Or can you **provide an entry** to the api? I can't find the entry point for the api call by myself.

Comment: Can you explain more ?

Comment: Because when the api is called, the metadata should always remain unchanged, which involves the problem of atomicity. So I want to know if the metadata will save a backup at the beginning of the api call.

Comment: which metadata are you talking about?

Comment: the total metadata，indexmetadata and aliasmetadata